# executeQuery() - return resultset

Tags: java, mysql, executequery

I am getting this error in return resultset.
*cannot convert results from Resultset to double*.

Isn't it possible to return a double? What should i do?

```
public double getBalance( String name )
{
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

   try 
   {
       selectBalance.setString( 1, name ); // specify last name

      // executeQuery returns ResultSet containing matching entries
      resultSet = selectBalance.executeQuery(); 


      while ( resultSet.next() )
      {
         resultSet.getDouble("balance");

      } // end while
   } // end try
   catch ( SQLException sqlException )
   {
      sqlException.printStackTrace();
   } // end catch

   return resultSet;
}
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: What is the query? What is the table? We need more info

Answer (score 1):

You should return a double if that's what you need :

```
public double getBalance( String name )
{
    double result = 0.0;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

   try 
   {
       selectBalance.setString( 1, name ); // specify last name

      // executeQuery returns ResultSet containing matching entries
      resultSet = selectBalance.executeQuery(); 


      while ( resultSet.next() )
      {
         result = resultSet.getDouble("balance");

      } // end while
   } // end try
   catch ( SQLException sqlException )
   {
      sqlException.printStackTrace();
   } // end catch

   return result;
}
```

Note that this would only return the value read from the last row of the result set, so if you expect multiple rows to be returned, consider returning a `List<Double>`.